# NHibernate, right way of working with proxies

Tags: nhibernate, proxy

I am working with a domain model that has been mapped in the following way:

- IProxy contract (including Id)
- Entity class implementing the contract

**Example:**

```
public class Product : IProductProxy {}
```

The class is mapped using the following logic:

```
<class name="Product" table="[Products]" lazy="true" proxy="IProductProxy">
```

Right now I found that the following methods work properly:

```
var result = session.Load<IProductProxy >(1);
var result = session.Get<IProductProxy>(1);
var result = session.Get<Product>(1);
```

While these methods throw "proxy exception" or "invalid cast exception"

```
var result = session.Load<Product>(1);
```

What I need to know is, what is the correct way of working with proxies and NHibernate. For example, I though that working directly with the interface would be fine, but when I try to do this:

```
// successful save
var result = session.Get<Customer>("ALFKI");
result.Name = "XXX";
session.Update(result);

// if error occurs I receive wrong exception
// cannot find mapping for ICustomerProxy ERROR
var result = session.Get<ICustomerProxy>("ALFKI");
result.Name = "XXX";
session.Update(result);
```

Should I always cast back to IProxy or should I use my Entity type?

Comment: What's the reason for providing an own proxy interface?

Comment: This is not the question

Comment: Providing an own proxy interface is not the normal usage of NHibernate proxies. If we know why you do this we might be able to better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var result = session.Load<Product>(1);` can't work. `Load()` returns a proxy if the entity isn't in the session yet. How should NHibernate create a proxy (inherited class) of type `Product` if you told NHibernate that proxies of that entity type only need to implement the `IProductProxy` interface?

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately I didn't find in the docs that Load returns always the proxied object.